# SVN repo "Not a Working Copy" after server replacement

Tags: svn, mac-osx-server

We had a Mac server die on us. All the data was stored on a RAID so transferring that to the replacement machine was seamless, but some of the folders were SVN repositories. I have installed SVN on the new server and run svnserve from the root folder. The svnserve runs fine, but users (using tortoise-svn) are unable to access anything and when I try using any svnadmin commands, I get a "Not a working copy" error.
I then tried performing a dump of the repo and loading it into a freshly created one, but this ha the same issue.

I have been searching all over but cannot find any solutions for this on a Mac server, so any advice would be very helpful. I'm not very familiar with SVN and the original setup was built by someone who has since left the company, so if there is any other information which would be helpful for answering this, let me know and I'll add it in.

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374313/svn-error-not-a-working-copy ? Have you checked and/or reset the owner and group of the repository folders (and below)?

Comment: Also, did you re-install macOS on the new server or did you restore directly from the backup?